# Can we change the UDID on my iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, hardware

Is there any way to change UDID of my iPhone/iPad?

or please suggest the way to generate fake UDID of the iPhone/iPad Device.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Short of jailbreaking, does a UDID ever change on an iDevice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5171581/short-of-jailbreaking-does-a-udid-ever-change-on-an-idevice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, download "UDID faker" from Cydia for a fully-featured solution (requires jailbreaking), or just use method swizzling on `- [UIDevice uniqueIdentifier]` if replacing it locally (within your app) is sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Your UDID is in the hardware, it's a hash composed of various serial numbers and other values.
You can't physically change your UDID.

And in order to generate fake UDID,you can use UDID faker,which requires jailbreaking.
UDIDFaker is a jailbreak app for the iPhone/iPod Touch that changes your default UDID of an app to anything you want. You can hit the random button for a random UDID. It also has a button to change your UDID back to default of the app.